# Enabling kerberos in pre prodution affect authentication?

Tags: linux, hadoop, kerberos, cloudera

I am Working on a 4 node pre-production Cloudera cluster CDH5.11. Current cluster Kerberos is not enabled. I want to enable Kerberos now. Will it affect current authentication while accessing the cluster?

Comment: This seems more relevant for [sf]

Comment: It'll affect authentication after it's enabled, yes. There is no current authentication. Kerberos is off

Comment: @cricket_007 Is there any other option to implement security in Hadoop environment.

Comment: Kerberos **is** Hadoop security. There is no other authentication mechanism, so it's not clear what you mean "current authentication" https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/security.html

Comment: There is option called Apache Ranger that is used in HortonWorks distribution like wise is there any other option instead of Kerberos..?